# freemarker ошибка на странице

Tags: java, freemarker

Все страницы отображаются нормально, только в одной отображается все кроме текста добавления который подтягивается с базы и отображения текст ошибки :

```
        37 перше повідомлення FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!): For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean),
     or "template output" , but this has evaluated to a method+sequence (wrapper: f.e.b.SimpleMethodModel): ==> message.authorName [in template "main.ftl" at line 22, column 15] ---- Tip: Maybe using obj.something() instead of obj.something will yield the desired value ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${message.authorName} [in template "main.ftl" at line 22, column 13] ~ Reached through: #nested [in template "parts/common.ftl" in macro "page" at line 9, column 1] ~ Reached through: @c.page [in template "main.ftl" at line 4, column 1] ---- Java stack trace (for programmers): ---- freemarker.core.NonStringOrTemplateOutputException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...] at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToTextualCommon(EvalUtil.java:511) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToStringOrMarkup(EvalUtil.java:389) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToStringOrMarkup(EvalUtil.java:358) at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.calculateInterpolatedStringOrMarkup(DollarVariable.java:100) at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:63) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:366) at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executedNestedContentForCollOrSeqListing(IteratorBlock.java:317) at 
freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedContent(IteratorBlock.java:271) at 
freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:242) at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:642) at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:107) at freemarker.core.ListElseContainer.accept(ListElseContainer.java:40) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:366) at freemarker.core.Environment.invokeNestedContent(Environment.java:618) at freemarker.core.BodyInstruction.accept(BodyInstruction.java:60) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:366) at freemarker.core.Environment.invoke(Environment.java:775) at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:83) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:330) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:336) at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:309) at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:384) at 
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:396) at 
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:309) at 
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:257) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:165) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) at 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) at 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at 
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at 
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at 
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at 
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) at 
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) at 
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at 
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) at 
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Вот код файла main.ftl на котором это происходит :

```
<#import "parts/common.ftl" as c>
<#import "parts/login.ftl" as l>

<@c.page>
<div>
    <@l.logout />
</div>

        <div>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Введіть повідомлення" />
                <input type="text" name="tag" placeholder="tag" />
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                <button type="submit">Добавити</button>
            </form>
        </div>
<#list messages as message>
<div>
    <b>${message.id}</b>
    <span>${message.text}</span>
    <i>${message.tag}</i>
    <strong>${message.authorName}</strong>
</div>
<#else>
No message
</#list>
</@c.page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на свой `Entity "Message"`:

несмотря на то, что в `main.ftl` у вас `message.authorName`, `getter` в `entity` должен называться `getAuthorName(){...}`, иначе он не подтягивается.

(небольшое пояснение: из-за несоблюдения заглавных\строчных букв в энтите и\или шаблоне метод не менеджится спрингом)

Comment: А почему вы не отредактировали  ваш первый ответ, а дали новый? Особой разницы между ними я не вижу.

Comment: Это был мой первый пост здесь. Хотел написать более ясно.

Comment: Хорошо, на будующее - под любым сообщением есть кнопка "правка", если надо что-то добавить или исправить.

Answer (score 0):

> Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean)

Проблема в поле `message.authorName`.

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего в return контроллера указываешь название ftl файла, а нужно прописать `return "redirect:/имя-маппинга-для-отображениея"` т.е. у тебя должен быть метод в контроллере, который возвращает все сообщения

```
@GetMappint("/allMessages")
public String getAllMessages(Model model)
```

А в методе, который отвечает за добавление сообщения(где PostMapping прописан) пропиши
`return "redirect:/allMessages"`
автоматически отработает GetMapping, который связан с методом, который отвечает за вывод сообщений